# Images are losing there height when set programmatically VS in XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

Setting images horizontally chained, with match constraint for both height and width with a ratio works perfectly in XML, but not programatically

My layout in xml that WORKS. The images span from left and right, and have their size determined by available screen space.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:text="TEST"
            android:id="@+id/nameText"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:id="@+id/first"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/second"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameText" app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            tools:text="NAMETEST"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/first"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/first"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/first"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/firstVotes"
        tools:text="NAMETEST"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/first"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:id="@+id/second"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/first" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/third" app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp" android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secondName"
            tools:text="NAMETEST"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/second"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/second"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/second"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secondVotes"
            tools:text="NAMETEST"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondName"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/second"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/second"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
            android:id="@+id/third"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/second"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/second" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thirdName"
            tools:text="NAMETEST"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/third"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/third"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/third"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thirdVotes"
            tools:text="NAMETEST"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/thirdName"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/third"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/third"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is (What I believe to be) the exact mirror of the above but done in code! The images are properly chained and spaced, I can verify via the TextViews, but the images lose all height and width and simply don't show in my app.

````
private class LeaderBoardView(ct: Context, leaderBoard: LeaderBoard): ConstraintLayout(ct) {
        init {
            this.id = View.generateViewId()

            val cs = ConstraintSet()
            cs.clone(this)

            val roleName = TextView(ct)
            roleName.text = leaderBoard.roleName
            roleName.id = View.generateViewId()
            roleName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            roleName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17F)
            cs.connect(roleName.id, TOP, PARENT, TOP)
            cs.connect(roleName.id, START, PARENT, START)
            cs.constrainWidth(roleName.id, WRAP)
            cs.constrainHeight(roleName.id, WRAP)
            this.addView(roleName)

            val first = ImageView(ct)
            first.id = View.generateViewId()
            cs.connect(first.id, TOP, roleName.id, BOTTOM)
            cs.constrainHeight(first.id, MATCH)
            cs.constrainWidth(first.id, MATCH)
            cs.setDimensionRatio(first.id,"1:1")
            this.addView(first)

            Picasso.get().load(leaderBoard.first!!.headshotURL).transform(PicassoCircleTransform()).into(first)

            val firstName = TextView(ct)
            firstName.id = View.generateViewId()
            firstName.text = leaderBoard.first!!.firstName
            firstName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            cs.connect(firstName.id, START, first.id, START)
            cs.connect(firstName.id, END, first.id, END)
            cs.connect(firstName.id, TOP, first.id, BOTTOM)
            cs.constrainWidth(firstName.id, WRAP)
            cs.constrainHeight(firstName.id, WRAP)
            this.addView(firstName)

            val firstVotes = TextView(ct)
            firstVotes.id = View.generateViewId()
            firstVotes.text = leaderBoard.first!!.firstName
            firstVotes.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            cs.connect(firstVotes.id, START, first.id, START)
            cs.connect(firstVotes.id, END, first.id, END)
            cs.connect(firstVotes.id, TOP, firstName.id, BOTTOM)
            cs.constrainWidth(firstVotes.id, WRAP)
            cs.constrainHeight(firstVotes.id, WRAP)
            this.addView(firstVotes)

            val second = ImageView(ct)
            second.id = View.generateViewId()
            cs.connect(second.id, TOP, first.id, TOP)
            cs.constrainHeight(second.id, MATCH)
            cs.constrainWidth(second.id, MATCH)
            cs.setDimensionRatio(second.id,"1:1")
            this.addView(second)

            Picasso.get().load(leaderBoard.second!!.headshotURL).transform(PicassoCircleTransform()).into(second)

            val secondName = TextView(ct)
            secondName.id = View.generateViewId()
            secondName.text = leaderBoard.first!!.firstName
            secondName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            cs.connect(secondName.id, START, second.id, START)
            cs.connect(secondName.id, END, second.id, END)
            cs.connect(secondName.id, TOP, second.id, BOTTOM)
            cs.constrainWidth(secondName.id, WRAP)
            cs.constrainHeight(secondName.id, WRAP)
            this.addView(secondName)

            val secondVotes = TextView(ct)
            secondVotes.id = View.generateViewId()
            secondVotes.text = leaderBoard.first!!.firstName
            secondVotes.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            cs.connect(secondVotes.id, START, second.id, START)
            cs.connect(secondVotes.id, END, second.id, END)
            cs.connect(secondVotes.id, TOP, secondName.id, BOTTOM)
            cs.constrainWidth(secondVotes.id, WRAP)
            cs.constrainHeight(secondVotes.id, WRAP)
            this.addView(secondVotes)

            cs.createHorizontalChainRtl(PARENT, START, PARENT, END, intArrayOf(first.id, second.id), null, ConstraintSet.CHAIN_SPREAD)


            cs.applyTo(this)
        }```
````

Comment: just to clarify when you do it programmatically, the view does not show up at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// You can also set ScalType attribute of imageView

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/img"/>

// also set placeholder in picasso     
Picasso.with(context).load(img url).placeholder(default_img).into(view name);

// you can also resize image with picasso
 Picasso.with(context).load(img url).placeholder(default_img).reSize(width,height).into(view name);
```

Comment: So the goal here is to not use XML at all. To clarify, these to bits of code are totally separate. One draws the view in code, the other gets drawn via inflate. I want to use the code only sample, but the images get set to 0x0 even with a place holder manually set. The XML works perfectly fine when inflated and images loaded in. I just don't know what I'm missing in my code that is in my XML!